# Using underscore when concatenating fields with expression in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression, qgsexpression

I am creating a new field with two existing fields and the result has to be like *1234_Abcd*. I used the string concatenation in the Field Calculator but it gives me *1234Abcd*. How can I insert the underscore (`_`) to separate both expressions?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
concat("Fieldname1", '_', "Fieldname2")
```

Also:

```
"Fieldname1" || '_' || "Fieldname2"
```

Comment: Another option would be to form an array with the field names, then use string to array with underscore as the separator. 

Also using doublequote would evaluate the field and return the feature attribute, once the proper field name is formed, if needed afterward use the attribute function.